# LAMP Stack - Update HTML Table - Not mapping to/from DB

Tags: php, html, lamp

Hello I have a basic HTML form **Index.html**

```
<html>
 <body>
 <form action="update.php" method="POST">
     Department: <input type="text" name="department"><br><br>
     Subname: <input type="text" name="subname"><br><br>
     Labels: <input type="text" name="labels"><br><br>
     Pagerduty: <input type="text" name="pagerduty"><br><br>
     Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On submit the following PHP script is executed to update my DB with the details. **update.php**

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$db = "dora";
$dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);
if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
 die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $department=$_POST['department'];
 $subname=$_POST['subname'];
 $labels=$_POST['labels'];
 $pagerduty=$_POST['pagerduty'];
 $description=$_POST['description'];
$query = "INSERT INTO dora (department, subname, labels, pagerduty, description)
VALUES ('$department', '$subname', '$labels', '$pagerduty', '$description')";
if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query)) {
      die('An error occurred when submitting your review.');
  } else {
    echo "Thanks for your review.";
  }
  }
?>
```

I then want another page showing a HTML table with the contents from the DB **Main.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$db = "dora";
$dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);
if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}
?>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <td>Department</td>
  <td>Subname</td>
  <td>Labels</td>
  <td>Pagerduty</td>
  <td>Description</td>
</tr>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM dora")
   or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['department']}</td>
    <td>{$row['subname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['labels']}</td>
    <td>{$row['pagerduty']}</td>
    <td>{$row['description']}</td>
   </tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine apart from two columns aren't mapping across, namely `Subname & Labels`

I've double checked my code but I cant spot the mistake, can anyone help me out?

I've restarted https etc. but nothing seems to work :(

**DORA SCHEMA**

MariaDB [dora]> show columns from dora;

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| TAB_ID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| department  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subname     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| labels      | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pagerduty   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The results from my table

```
Department  Subname Labels  Pagerduty   Description
1                             4              5
1                             4              5
sdfsdf                        adfasdfad      adfadfadfa
```

Comment: Silly question but... have you verified that the values for subname and labels indeed get inserted (using, say, phpMyAdmin)?

Comment: +---------+
| subname |
+---------+
|             |
|             |
+---------+ yeah I checked, nothing is going in :(

Comment: Only for those two fields, all others are working

Comment: oh okay... so the fail is happening at the `INSERT` and not when you are pulling the record and iterating over the returned recordset in your `while`, correct?

Comment: Correct, I just cant spot the error, i suspect a typo or something as all other feilds are mapping they all have the same type too, i.e. varchar(200) | utf8_general_ci

Comment: check the following, for the *table schema* of `dora`: `column type` and `length` for columns/fields: **subname** and **labels**

Comment: All are varchar(200)

Comment: The entries don't exceed this

Comment: Could you show us the dora table schema?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Form action references info.php, your script is called update.php

Comment: Typo, it was....

Comment: So this is still an issue? If so, just to make sure, when you do an `INSERT` the other fields (`TAB_ID`, `department`, `pagerduty`, and `description`) get populated?

Comment: Correct they do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it is working fine . the only difference is that im using InnoDB which should be the same. Try the following:

1 change those columns names.

2 recreate your DB.

3 make sure there is no trigers setting the two column to plank

Comment: Yes this was my next step now i have exhausted the help. I will try and let you know. thanks for the help!